# Openshift Java SQLite, cannot open/create database file

Tags: java, sqlite, openshift

I am trying to create/access an SQLite database file in an openshift environment using Java. The code works fine on the local Tomcat server on which I am testing but does not work when I deploy it to the openshift environment.

The relevant code is below and based on the logs I have been able to identify the line which fails:

**Log:**

```
Apr 23, 2015 3:37:33 PM my_package.HelloWorld_sl doPost
INFO: jdbc:sqlite:/var/lib/openshift/5522c491fcf9335ab7000053/app-root/data/test
Apr 23, 2015 3:37:33 PM my_package.HelloWorld_sl doPost
INFO: Class Loaded
Apr 23, 2015 3:37:33 PM my_package.HelloWorld_sl doPost
INFO: Trying Database connection establishment
```

(I get nothing after the above)

**Java code:**

```
..
db_filename="jdbc:sqlite:"+ "data" + File.separatorChar + "test.db";
LOGGER.info(db_filename);

Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
LOGGER.info("Class Loaded");
LOGGER.info("Trying Database connection establishment"); //I see this message in logs, but not the next LOGGER message so it is the following line that fails.
dbc =DriverManager.getConnection(db_filename);
LOGGER.info("Database connection established");
```

Thanks in advance.
Bob

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the db file is either not where you think it is or you don't have permissions to access that file. 
is LOGGER.info(db_filename); returning what you expect?
If so, do you (your program)  have write permissions ?

also 'dbc' is a typo , right? Supposed to be 'jdbc'

Comment: dbc is not a typo, dbc is declared earlier as follows: Connection dbc=null; Also the db file is where it is expected as I am able to write/read plain text files in same folder as that of the db file.